# Adding image to CompletionWindow avalonedit control

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I have a list of words for completion window in avalonedit control. The list is working great and everything is displayed properly. my question is how do I add images to the list (each row a different image).

```
public static IList<ICompletionData> ReturnHtmlList(IList<ICompletionData> data)
{

    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("doctype"));
    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("a"));
    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("abbr"));
    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("acronym"));
    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("address"));
    data.Add(new MyCompletionData("applet"));
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Image property on ICompletionData interface?